# How to ping between two machines in VirtualBox?

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I'm a complete beginner, and this is my first assignment. I'm supposed to create a virtual network to connect two virtual machines, and connect the two machines to the host. I believe I have done this.

Then I'm supposed to show that the two machines are connected by pinging one from the other and vice versa, however I have no idea how to do this. None of the things I have found on google works, I'm not sure if I'm just not using the right command or if there is something wrong with the network connection. So please, can someone tell me how to ping from one machine to the other?

Comment: This seems a lot like a homework assignment.

Comment: It isn't, but I'm doing assignments from a beginner's course, hence why I don't have anyone who can help me

Comment: See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177809/how-to-ping-ubuntu-guest-on-virtualbox) and this [one](https://superuser.com/questions/119732/how-to-do-networking-between-virtual-machines-in-virtualbox).

Answer (score 0):

Change The Network adapter of two Virtual Machine to **VirtualBox Host Only Adapter** and Reboot The Guest Machines And Try To Ping

Mostly Virtual Machines are connected to NAT network

You cant access the internet in this adapter l. You may use the NAT or Bridged Adapter

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise change the network setting to **Bridged Adapter** and restart network. it will work to access the internet and two virtual machines also.

Comment: Your answer is unclear, please.